# Nuxt 3 dynamic route due to Strapi API leads to 404 on direct call / reload

Tags: routes, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I've got a Nuxt3 website which has a blog which is based on Strapi.io. So the blog posts are loaded via the API. After the website is deployed via `nuxt generate` the posts which are published till the deployment work fine. (There are static folders for each blog post generated by `nuxt generate`)
BUT if i publish a new post it can't not be opened like url.de/blog/new-post. As there is no folder on the server generated by nuxt of course it leads to a 404.

But how can i manage to build the folder and contents on the first call of the new post?

What i tried but it does not work:

```js
routeRules: {
  "/blog/**": { swr: true },
}
```

Comment: Do you re-generate the website with a webhook everytime you publish a new post? https://strapi.io/blog/webhooks Setting this with Netlify (for example) is quite simple and will solve your issue IMO.

Comment: Actually i do not, because i only deploy `.output/public` I was looking for another solution but i guess i have to do it like this. Thanks

Comment: When you have your CI building your app, it doesn't really matter what you deploy. Will still be the final bundle. Or are you bundling and manually drag-and-drop/FTP'ing the thing? If yes, I rather recommend git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such purpose, you need to use Strapi's webhooks: https://strapi.io/blog/webhooks

It can be integrated fairly easily into Netlify or any other good modern PaaS with ease. It will then trigger a rebuild of your app for you.